# Simulate local file specifications in RPGLE subprocedure

Tags: rpgle, rpg, ibm-midrange

I'm very excited about the new "local F specs" coming in V6R1 - see:

http://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/rpg/v6r1-rpg-enhancements.html

Does anyone know a way to simulate this in V5R4 in a SRVPGM procedure?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only define them globally, but you can process just that file in a single subprocedure.

Comment: This could work, just remember to define the file as USROPN, and then open and close the file in the procedure that you are using it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can only simulate that by making modules that only processes *one* file globally. So the file scope is still global, but you don't share it with other files. if you really would want to have a file per procedure you'd have to make a module for each procedure. I don't recommend that. Just too many modules. But maybe your happy with the one-module-per-file style, otherwise you have to wait like me for v6r1 ;)

Comment: I agree.  You can also have the same file opened twice in your program if you name it differently in the F-spec and then use the EXTFILE keyword.  You'll also need to rename the fields as well.  I like to use the PREFIX keyword for that.